# Difference between user-drag and user-select in CSS

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, draggable

What are the main differences between the `user-select` and the `user-drag` attribute? Also are they supported on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is, that `user-select` allows you to select and then copy something (if you want it), but `user-drag` allows you to drag something such as HTML elements.

I know that `user-select` can be used in different browsers, but you should set the CSS rules like shown below:

```
-webkit-user-select: all; 
-moz-user-select: all; 
-ms-user-select: all;
user-select: all;
```

Comment: can you please tell me about user-drag attributes support on all browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

User select is specific to `text` as mentioned in [User Select - MDN web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) by default, user-select is enable to texts. To disable that property use the below-mentioned CSS stylings.

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

[User Drag](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-drag) is generic, that can be applied to `div, image, p, etc.,`

```
<p draggable="true">Contents</p> //Enable dragging
<img src="image.jpg" draggable="false" alt="can't be dragged"></img> //Disable dragging
```

Below is the CSS for user-drag

```
-webkit-user-drag:none;
-moz-user-drag:none;
-o-user-drag:none;
user-drag:none;
```

Comment: What is the relation between the two variants of inhibiting drag? Is `draggable="false"` equivalent to the css in the last box?

Comment: [draggable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp) is an HTML attribute, upon setting it to true, when we select(mouse select) the content and can drag it, but it will be momentary.